# Find unused variables in Angular 8

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, angular8, tslint

Is there any plugin available for VS CODE which can indicate all the variables that I have defined in the TS file but never used either in same TS or corresponding template (HTML) file ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late but have you checked Angular [lint](https://angular.io/cli/lint) and combining with eslint [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars)? In my case, these 2 combination works well specifically for unused variables